# Get values of a spesific column in Kendo Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendospreadsheet

For example, I have a column like this :

**A**

50

65

73

NULL

63

I can get values of selected range

```
let sh = $("#spreadsheet").getKendoSpreadsheet();
var sheet = sh.activeSheet();
var range = sheet.selection();
var values = range.values();
```

and want to get all values of **A** column without selecting. Is there a method in kendo-spreadsheet like i want? What should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values in a specific range using the `range` function, like this:

```
var spreadsheet = $("#spreadsheet").data("kendoSpreadsheet");
var values = spreadsheet.sheets()[0].range("A1:A3").values();
```

You can see a demo in the following snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.220/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<button id="test">Test</button>
<div id="spreadsheet"></div>
<script>
    $("#spreadsheet").kendoSpreadsheet({
        sheets: [{
            rows: [{
                cells: [{ value: "A" }, { value: "B" }, { value: "C" }]
            }, {
                cells: [{ value: "1" }, { value: "2" }, { value: "3" }]
            }, {
                cells: [{ value: "4" }, { value: "5" }, { value: "6" }]
            }]
        }]
    });
  
    $("#test").click(function(e) {
        var spreadsheet = $("#spreadsheet").data("kendoSpreadsheet");
        alert(spreadsheet.sheets()[0].range("A1:A3").values().join(", "));
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```